# Spark Not Finding S3 File

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am attempting to read a file located on S3 with Apache Spark (Pyspark) with the command(s) below, and getting the errors below. The file is a gzipped JSON in a year/month/day/hour/minute partition. I have successfully pulled months worth of data from this store, but I am getting the error due to this one particular file. I am running this on an AWS Sagemaker Notebook connected to AWS EMR.

**Commands**

```
# both fail
spark.read.json('s3://my_bucket/my_prefix/2021/08/31/08/53/').show()
spark.read.json('s3://my_bucket/my_prefix/2021/08/31/08/53/my_file.gz').show()
```

**Error**

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 22) (ip-10-251-32-235.eu-west-1.compute.internal executor 19): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://my_bucket/my_prefix/2021/08/31/08/53/my_file.gz'
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:159)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:85)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:232)
```

What I have tried to far:

- Restarting the spark cluster
- Verified the file; it was previously updated 10 days prior to this error
- Verified that this was uniquely a Spark issue; I was able to see the file with the non-spark command below

```
# this command successfully prints out the erroneous file
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='my_prefix/2021/08/31/08/53'):
    print(my_bucket_object)
```

- Creating a Table and Refreshing it

```
# Tried this
spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW bad_file USING json OPTIONS" + 
      " (path 's3://my_bucket/my_prefix/2021/08/31/08/53/')")
spark.sql('REFRESH TABLE bad_file')

# And this
spark.read.json('s3://my_bucket/my_prefix/2021/08/31/08/53/my_file.gz').cache().unpersist()
```

I've seen this is a common issue that comes up, but most people seem to fix it by refreshing the table. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  Go to your S3 Bucket file and "Make public using ACL"
[S3 Actions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abqq0.png)